# How to apply Custom font family to your flutter app?

Tags: android, ios, flutter

how one can apply a custom font family on a whole flutter app??

Comment: then where i can answer this ques???

Comment: When you create a question, there's a separate area that you can use to provide an answer to that same question! I recommend editing this question so that it only contains the question portion, then providing a new answer using the input box nearer the bottom of this page :)

Comment: done with that thanks....

Answer (score 0):

Solution : To apply font to your whole flutter app you just add the following code in your main function

```
void main()
{
  runApp(new MaterialApp(
    home: new SplashScreen(),
    theme: new ThemeData(
      fontFamily: 'GoogleSans'
    ),
  ));
}
```